# Doing 3blue1brown style animations in Blender

Tags: modeling, animation

I wanted to know we can do complex mathematical 2D Animations in blender. I am trying to do something like the famous 3blue1brown youtube channel videos. Please take a look at [Sample Video](https://youtu.be/sD0NjbwqlYw?t=338) for example. Basically my purpose is not just to draw 2D objects but to control them alone a path governed by mathematical equations.

Comment: try Animation Nodes Addon. Its is really good for this kind of things

Comment: @HenrikD Thanks for the suggestion. I will take a look at it.